# C# Generic Typed List vs Type Arrays for primitive value types

Tags: c#, data-structures, computer-science, software-design

What are benefits of the two vs cons?

which one to use and when?

I have been able to understand the following difference so far

List<T>

- Dynamic resizing / dynamic memory allocation
- - If Count == Capacity, new memory allocation is provided and elements are copied from older memory, which is less performant compared to arrays
- Supports O(1) Add, remove, and indexing
- Does it support continuous memory allocation for value-types like Typed arrays?

T[] - Typed Arrays

- Dynamically allocated fixed continuous memory allocation at compile-time
- Supports O(1) indexing; what about run-time complexity for adding or removing elements?

N/A - Theoretical question

Comment: The `List<T>` class uses an array internally to store the items. If you don't need the additional functionality provided by a collection, you should use an array as a general rule.

Comment: An exception may be when realising the results of a LINQ query. Calling `ToList` will create a new `List<T>` while calling `ToArray` will create a new `Buffer<T>` and then make an extra call to `ToArray` on that and copy all items to a new array. That overhead may be significant for large result sets. Then again, it usually won't matter.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for this insight. 

Interesting to know the implications of LINQ. Does that mean it’s better to use for or for-each loops than LINQ since there is no recreation of lists or arrays?

Comment: There is always an overhead associated with LINQ, so it will almost always perform worse than the alternative. The difference will mostly be insignificant though, so the more succinct code LINQ enables is generally preferable. My comment wasn't about using or not using LINQ though. It was about whether to call `ToList` or `ToArray` on a LINQ query to get the final results.